# Windows 10 make Android-like folders on desktop

Tags: windows-10, desktop, user-interface

I like to be able to see my wallpaper, so I want to just have one folder with all my program shortcuts on the desktop. However, it's not very slick to have to open up Windows explorer to access the shortcuts.

I like the interface on Android OS, where tapping on a folder expands the icon so you can access the contents. Is something like this possible on Windows 10?

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: There exists third-party programs that offer this functionality.

Comment: try StartDock Fenses: http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/

Answer (score 3):

I actually recommend getting [Visual Studio Express (Free)](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-express-vs.aspx) and ***creating an interface of your own.***

I recommend this because it **doesn't involve third parties**, and because **it's free and very easy.**

The general idea would be to:

- create a VB project,
- set the window to **no titlebar**,
- set the **window position fixed to X Y** on some place on your screen,
- and **put the .exe on your desktop** near the place where the window position was set.

.

A **completely unstyled** window with buttons created in VS:

[image: Form1 with buttons]

Which, **after removing the title bar, adding more buttons**, and setting images on those buttons, you can get something like this:

[image: Office icons]

Each button would have a handler that looks like so:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Shell("notepad")
    'OR
    Process.Start("word.exe")
End Sub
```

.

**It's really easy code, it's a free IDE, everything is drag-and-drop.**

What you get is full customization, no third parties, and some VB experience!

Comment: The issue with this solution is lack of flexibility. You can't easily drag-drop shortcuts into existing folders without needing to spin-up visual studio and compile a project for every change. Move folders around. Collapse folders into a single icon size. Make sure the collapsed icon doesn't hide an existing desktop icon. Etc. The DIY approach seems like it would just be frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

you can try the [7stacks](http://alastria.com/software/7stacks/) icon based program launcher

[image: Android-like folders on desktop]

Source: [Ghacks](http://www.ghacks.net/2016/02/02/7stacks-icon-based-program-launcher-for-windows/)